# finding a rational number u, that satisfies a countable number of inequalities

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

This is stated in a proof I am reading:

They arrive at two real numbers x, and y which are not equal. Then they say, choose a rational number such that $u(x-y) \ne 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. But how do we know that such a number u exist?

My attempt for showing this is this: If $x-y$ is not an integer multiple of $2\pi$ we are done. If not, we have that $x-y=2K\pi$. And now I must find some u. if u could be any real number, it would be easy, because than $u=\pi$ works fine, but what when u is restricted to the rational case?

I feel that this should not be so dificult, but do we need number theory techniques to show it?

Comment: It is unclear .You choose u or k or both? Or is it for all k\in Z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just choose $u$ small enough.  If $x-y=2K\pi$, choose $u=\frac 1{2K}$.  Then $u(x-y)=\pi \neq 2k\pi, k \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: Thank you, I see that works.